# Whats the difference about defining a variable as Function or Function() in dart

Tags: dart

What's the diference about setting the type of a variable as `Function` or `Function()`?

```dart
Function function1 = () { print("1"); };
Function() function2 = () { print("2"); };

// Both works 
function1();
function2();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Function` does just say that your variable points to a `Function` but does not require this variable to point to a function with a specific signature.

`Function()` actually gives an analyzer warning on my machine because this is not entirely correct. Instead it should have been `void Function() function2 = () { print("2"); };`. This specifies that `function2` must point to a function which does not return anything and takes zero arguments.

The last is also what would be declared by Dart itself if you have used `var` or `final` instead of specifying the type.

The difference becomes clear if you change the method to take an argument:

```
Function function1 = (int a) { print("1"); }; // works
void Function() function2 = (int a) { print("2"); }; // error
```